# Which IP address I have to use to access Ratchet server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, supervisord, ratchet

I have setup ratchet on amazon EC2 instance.

It is running fine, but I am not able to connect with the public IP address of the instance as well as the url.

Following is the screenshot showing ratchet is running.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the service is running on the right IP address (not only on 127.0.0.1) and that you enabled access in the security group to that particular port.

Comment: The port is open and accessible to all.
like 0.0.0.0:2345

Comment: Did you open the port in the sg? Could you paste here the output of the following: ```netstat -plant | grep 2345```

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2345            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   -

Comment: Did you add port 2345 to the security group?